# Display SQL query results in php

Tags: php, sql

I was trying to calculate the total of each column in the database and display it on the webpage using php. 
But it just gives me

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [sum(food1)] => 6
)
```

which I just want **'6'** as my result.

Here is my code

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    $foodid=('food'."$i");
    echo $foodid;
    $food_query = mysql_query("select sum($foodid) from orderdetail where date between '$fm_date' and '$to_date'");
    $ttl_food= mysql_fetch_array($food_query);
    print_r($ttl_food[$i]);
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried indexing the array?

Comment: You need `mysql_fetch_row`. **Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

The result of `SELECT SUM` or any other functions like `COUNT()`, `MAX()` etc. is always a recordset. You need to just take the first element of the array of rows (even if only one row exists). Just `$your_rows_array[0]`.

To avoid having strange names like `[sum(food1)]` you can `SELECT SUM($foodid) AS mysum FROM ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one by giving an `alias` name `sumoffood` to your aggregate function's output

```
$food_query = mysql_query("select sum($foodid) as sumoffood from orderdetail where date between '$fm_date' and '$to_date'");
```

and then use

```
$ttl_food= mysql_fetch_assoc($food_query);
echo $ttl_food['sumoffood'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select sum(field) as sum
```

and

```
ttl_food['sum'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
$foodid=('food'."$i");
echo $foodid;
$food_query = mysql_query("select sum(field) as sum from orderdetail 
where date between '$fm_date' and '$to_date'");
$ttl_food= mysql_fetch_array($food_query);
print_r($ttl_food['sum']);
```

Comment: You answer is not right. $ttl_food[$i]['sum'] is not right. It must be $ttl_food['sum'].